# Does Drupal have a system for noticing and logging changes to records?

Tags: 7, feeds, rules

Does Drupal have a system for noticing and logging changes to existing content into a database or a file log?
I am interested in something equivalent to database triggers.

I am also interested in Feeds in particular as a lot of the data will be loaded from external sources. Do Feed imports have such a facility?

Comment: Nodes do have such a system, yes: https://drupal.org/node/320614. It can't be implemented at the database level, as not all the db engines that Drupal supports themselves support triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Track Field Changes](https://drupal.org/project/track_field_changes) module which appears to have little support. And also a -dev version of [Node Changes](https://drupal.org/project/nodechanges) module with many more contributors and more recent updates.

Both modules allow you to track field level changes on Nodes essentially. From Node Changes:

> This module stores the changes of a node into a field attached to
>   comments allowing to display a kind-of activity stream on the node
>   much like on drupal.org issues just with a lot less custom code.

I don't believe either makes use of database triggers.